# I'm having a missing 1 required positional argument issue, but I'm giving it an argument..what am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, oop, stack

I'm trying to run a leetcode solution through a debugger so I can see how the solution works.  Its number 20 on parenthesis.  This is what I've plugged into the debugger..am I missing something?

[screencapture of what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGBGl.png)

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        parenthesis = {"}":"{", 
        "]":"[", 
        ")":"("
        }
        stack = []
        for i in s:
           if i in parenthesis:
               if not stack or paren[i] != stack[-1]: 
                   return False
        
               else:
                    stack.pop()
           else:
                stack.append(i)
        return stack == []

Solution.isValid("{[]}")
```

I've tried making an instance of the class but I still get the same issue.

Comment: `Solution.isValid("{[]}")` should be `Solution().isValid("{[]}")`. Since it is a class method, so you need to call the `isValid()` method on a class instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```isValid()``` is a method and so you need to instantiate ```Solution``` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `Object a` of a `Class Solution`

**Note** you need to use `print` statment for the output. without `print` statement your console will show nothing.

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        parenthesis = {"}":"{", 
        "]":"[", 
        ")":"("
        }
        stack = []
        for i in s:
           if i in parenthesis:
               if not stack or parenthesis[i] != stack[-1]: 
                   return False
               else:
                    stack.pop()
           else:
                stack.append(i)
        return stack == []

a=Solution()
print(a.isValid("{[]}"))
```

**Output:-**

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the object of a class first.

```
sol = Solution()
print(sol.isValid("{[]}")
```